# Comparing enums with arguments

Tags: ios, swift, enums

Here are some enums I have:

```
enum SlideTemplate : Equatable {
    case centered(content: SlideContent)
    case horizontalSplit(leftContent: SlideContent, rightContent: SlideContent)
    case empty

    static func == (lhs: SlideTemplate, rhs: SlideTemplate) -> Bool {
        // not sure what to do here
    }
}

enum SlideContent {
    case text(content: String)
    case image(content: UIImage)
}

struct Slide {
    let template: SlideTemplate
}
```

Now I want to check what type of template a Slide has.

```
func getSlideTemplate(slide: Slide) {
    if slide.template == SlideTemplate.centered {
        print("centered")
    } else if slide.template == SlideTemplate.horizontalSplit {
        print("horizontalSplit")
    } else {
        print("empty")
    }
}
```

The above function obviously doesn't work. It states:

> "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SlideTemplate' and '(SlideContent, SlideContent) -> SlideTemplate'"

I'm not sure how to fix this. I looked up other cases of comparing enums, but I couldn't apply those to this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Main idea is about comparing related values and those `raw` values if needed. So, you `==` func can be like this:

```
static func == (lhs: SlideTemplate, rhs: SlideTemplate) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (.centered(lvalue), .centered(rvalue)):
        return lvalue == rvalue
    case let (.horizontalSplit(lleft, lright), .horizontalSplit(rleft, rright)):
        return lleft == rleft && lright == rright
    case (.empty, .empty):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

For example, if you don't need to compare `raw` values of `.centered`, you can check only related values:

```
...
case (.centered, .centered):
    return true
...
```

And as @user28434 mentioned, you should make `SlideContent` conforms to `Equatable` protocol as well.

```
static func ==(lhs: SlideContent, rhs: SlideContent) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case let (.text(lcontent), .text(rcontent)):
        return lcontent == rcontent
    case let (.image(lcontent), .image(rcontent)):
        return lcontent == rcontent
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

And now you can compare via `==` full-typed-values like:

```
if slide.template == SlideTemplate.centered(content: SlideContent.text(content: "SomeContent")) {
    print("centered for SomeContent")
}
```

To fast compare associated values you can use `if case` construction:

```
if case .centered = slide.template {
    print("centered")
}
```

---

**Conclusion**.

- If you want to know "what type of `SlideTemplate` contains this property" - use `if case .centered = slide.template { ... }` way without implementing `Equatable` protocol.
- If you want to fully compare `SlideTemplate` properties - implement `Equatable` protocol and compare them with `==`.

Comment: Note: `SlideContent` should be `Equatable` too for full comparing (first code segment).

Comment: @pacification I implemented this. However, the function in my original question still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check enum value in `getSlideTemplate` you actually don't need `==` at all.

Just use `if case`:

```
func getSlideTemplate(slide: Slide) {
    if case SlideTemplate.centered = slide.template {
        print("centered")
    } else if case SlideTemplate.horizontalSplit = slide.template {
        print("horizontalSplit")
    } else {
        print("empty")
    }
}
```

or, even better, `switch`:

```
func getSlideTemplate(slide: Slide) {
    switch slide.template {
    case .centered:
        print("centered")
    case .horizontalSplit:
        print("horizontalSplit")
    case .empty:
        print("empty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This could work for you if you compare content as well

```
enum SlideTemplate : Equatable {
    case centered(content: SlideContent)
    case horizontalSplit(leftContent: SlideContent, rightContent: SlideContent)
    case empty

    static func == (lhs: SlideTemplate, rhs: SlideTemplate) -> Bool {
        // not sure what to do here

        switch  lhs {
        case .centered(let content):
            switch rhs {
            case .centered(content: let rhsContent):
                return content == rhsContent
            default:
                return false
            }
        case .horizontalSplit(let leftContent, let rightContent):
            switch rhs {
            case .horizontalSplit(let rhsLeftContent, let rhsRightContent):
                return leftContent == rhsLeftContent && rightContent == rhsRightContent
            default:
                return false
            }
        case .empty:
            switch rhs {
            case .empty:
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}

enum SlideContent: Equatable {

    case text(content: String)
    case image(content: UIImage)

    static func ==(lhs: SlideContent, rhs: SlideContent) -> Bool {
        switch lhs {
        case .text(let content):
            switch  rhs {
            case .text(let rhsContent):
                return content == rhsContent
            default:
                return false
            }
        case .image(let content):
            switch rhs {
            case .image(let rhsContent):
                return content == rhsContent
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }
}
```